# Why in the limit ,$[\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}]$ is half-open?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A_n=\left[\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right]$
>
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=(0,1]$

we are dealing with $\left[0+\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right]$

**Question**:

Why is the interval closed at one but not at zero?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be better to say that the interval is half open, rather than "clopen", which means something else.

Comment: What do you mean by the limit of a sequence of intervals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is closed at $1$ because $1\in\left[\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right]$, for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

On the other hand, if $x\in(0,1]$, then $x\in\left[\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right]$ if $n$ is large enough. But $0$ belongs to none of those intervals.

Answer (score 5):

Because doesn't matter how big $n$ is, you will never get to the point $0$ itself. On the other hand the point $1$ is contained in every interval in the sequence.